# Не подключается client Socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io, javascript

Ошибка вида:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined **socket.io.js:11**
```

Ругается на строку:

```
var client = require('socket.io-client');
```

Подключение такое:

```
<script src="/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Кто сталкивался?

Comment: В папке с проектом есть папка node_modules в ней модуль socket.io

Comment: Документацию не читай, не то подключай. 

Нафиг ты клиенту подключаешь серверный модуль?) В socket.io есть же папочка: client. Там лежит файл socket.io.js, во его и подключай.

Comment: @IOleg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Это потому что `require` для кода node.js, а не браузера.

`require` - это только работает на сервере. [Например](http://socket.io/):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Вот так как надо использовать socket.io в браузере:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Конечно, нужно убедиться, что socket.io установлен, и что путь `/socket.io/socket.io.js` существует, и что сервер его оказывает.

Comment: Что это? У клиента все рано нужно подключить библу js - в этом и проблема

Comment: Сам node.js должен отдавать браузеру библиотеку по адресу /socket.io/socket.io.js
Но почему-то не делает это

Comment: Нужно делать `npm install socket.io`. Уже сделал?

Comment: Установлен уже. Проблема сохранилась

Comment: При запуске server.js выдает   info  - socket.io started